# What stroke width Instagram is using for its icons and how to get same results?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, stroke, pixel, outline

I'm designing on Illustrator icons for a new app, when I use 1px stroke and preview on mobile they look very thin and when I use 2px stroke they look a bit bold while Instagram icons look and feel perfect.
I tried to reproduce the same but I think they use something around 1.3px stroke which is not pixel perfect for me.
Could you explain me if my understanding is wrong and how I can get same result as Instagram icons?

here is an example, hope it helps to understand my point:

Image 1 is 1px stroke:

[image: This is 1px stroke]

Image 2 is Instagram example:

[image: This is instagram example]

Image 3 is 2px stroke:

[image: This is 2px stroke]

Comment: Hi Youness Mazouz, welcome to GD.SE, could you put some example image icons at the question please. Not all the people who answer here are Instagram users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the case, but sometimes the icons are made with a double stroke to mimic a fake stroke width. At the icons below there are three different strokes:

1. 1px
2. 1px black + 2px grey
3. 2px

[image: icons]

This is the second icon structure:

[image: icon structure]

Comment: Thanks Danielillo, it worked!
I used as in your example 1px + 1.3px all black and it gave a fantastic result.

Comment: Glad to help...